# Air pressure levitation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, levitation

How much mass can you levitate with air? Take air hockey table for example, pressurised air is pushed through holes and they levitate a disk but how much mass is possible?

I think it would probably depend on three things; the mass of the disk, the surface area of the disk and the air pressure. (Possibly on the size and number of holes on the table as well)

Comment: There are big hovercrafts.

Comment: I'm really looking for a way to quantify it, for example, for a specific pressure how much can it lift

Answer (score 2):

This is a "how long is a piece of string" question - there isn't really any limit.

Four of [these devices](http://www.movetechuk.com/hovairairskates.html) can levitate 240 tons. Use more than four, and you can levitate "thousands of tons" according to the manufacturer's website.

Answer (score 0):

The table can be modeled as a porous medium (using Darcy's law) with a constant air pressure reservoir beneath it.  The flow interaction between the puck and the table can be modeled as a aerodynamic lubrication flow, involving the same viscous flow equations as for hydrodynamic lubrication, but with a compressible fluid.